# Euler Discretization in Python 2 forecasting

Tags: python-2.7, forecasting, yahoo-finance

I tried to do an Euler discretization in Python to predict the stock price
    one period ahead from a training on Udemy using the following code: https://docs.google.com/document/d/e/2PACX-1vRilqx3Eib6Ieefbdwcd6WSW8SCWeD9egRjbLVF8TL4VlsrdihkRJUcvo7f22_kSs1bDLqmibHxYGo/pub

For the last line of code I get this error (SEE THE GOOGLE DOC FOR THE FULL 
    ERROR). Can you help be figure this out?

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-05f819bc8a3b> in <module>()
1 for t in range(1, t_intervals + 1):
----> 2     S[t] = S[t-1] * np.exp((r - 0.5 * stdev ** 2) * delta_t + stdev * 
delta_t ** 0.5 * Z[t])
```

Comment: The Google doc is actually here: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1O0SiUuvriAQ1w-P7N56RFPDnf0CtIUfrc_JqWt1VUbE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Your question should be self-contained; the vast majority of people won't bother to check an external link (which might become invalid any time, rendering the question useless for future visitors).